# Source Insight cannot jump normally

Tags: source-insight

Source Insight cannot jump to C++ header files such as iostream, vector, etc., as well as STL containers. The display in the software is gray. I want to jump normally, how should I configure it?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWKb7.png)

I used ctrl and left mouse button to jump， I want to jump normally, how should I configure it?